# How to change the variable value declared before for loop and tried to change value in for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops

The following is my code:

```
bool rValue = false;
for(int i=0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
  some code...
  ...
  ...
  rValue  = true

}

std::cout << "rValue is " << rValue << std::endl;
```

Output of the above code is `rValue is false`. Why? Why didn't the value of the rValue variable change?

Comment: Can you show "some code" ?

Comment: The key is in some code... ... ... Check your code. Especially for `break` or `continue`. Most probably, in your `some code` you have `break` and `rValue = true` is not executed, or you have some conditions with `continue` and `rValue = true` is never executed again. A `goto` is possible, too, but I hope you don't use it :) The other possible reason is to have a local variable `rValue`, defined inside the `for` loop, which shadows the outer one. If you compile with all possible warnings, probably you would get a warning, if this is the case.

Comment: So, that's not the actual code you're using. Were that the code, you'd be fine. What is the missing piece? One obvious idea is that `rValue = true` is guarded behind an `if`, or you're `break`ing/`continue`ing before the assignment.

Comment: It seems you have two variables names `rValue` in different scopes and hence the problem.Difficult to say unless you show some code.

Comment: I suspect two possible causes: there is a (new) variable named rValue in the for-block that shadows the one outside or there is a break in the for-block that triggers before it is set to true.

Comment: Thanks @all fro help, i fixed the issue as there are "if" statements in loop, that avoids to change the value of rValue variable.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect somewhere inside your loop you have declaration `bool rValue`. So its changing the `rValue` under loop scope. not the parent scope one.

and also If you quit the loop before reaching the inner assignment statement it will not effect. You can check that in a debugger or place a `std::cout` before assignment